# Links url layout in cross-platform xamarin

Tags: c#, layout, xamarin

I need to show a url like `email`, `facebook` or `a site` in my application in cross-platform Xamarin.

I have this code but shows in text:

```
layout.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "Email:", HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center });
        layout.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = loader.Contacts.Email, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center });

        layout.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "FaceBook:", HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center });
        layout.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = loader.Contacts.Facebook, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center });
```

how i can make it?

Thanks

Comment: You can use TapGestures on label.

Comment: But how i can change the code above that appears like a link in the app, and pass for web browser or for email program in smarphone.